# Kotlin матрица TextView

Tags: java, android, kotlin

как можно задать матрицу из TextView ? Делаю сейчас так

```
var array = arrayOf<Array<TextView>>()
    array[0][0] = findViewById(R.id.a1)
```

Ошибка идет на присвоении, TextView уже создана и если присваивать ее к обычной переменной, то все работает

Comment: Как выглядит "ошибка на присвоении"? Это в рантайме или ошибка этапа компиляции?

Comment: Функция `arrayOf` создаёт массив заданного размера. В вашем примере кода, размер массива равен **нулю** и при попытке записать в `array[0][0]` вы должны получить вполне очевидный эксепшен: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Чтобы это исправить, либо используйте мутабельный лист, либо инициализируйте массив нужными значениями в момент создания.